# AWS S3 library for file upload from QNX java

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I want to transfer files from QNX platform using java to AWS S3 bucket. The maximum size of a jar file in QNX platform is <4MB.

But AWS java library is very big >40MB. Are there any smaller size AWS s3 client library available for java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to include all AWS java library. You only need to add the core (aws-java-sdk-core) and s3 (aws-java-sdk-s3) which sums up only to less than 2MB.